# Prove compactness of a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be subset the of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ consisting of all matrices $(\langle x_i,y_j\rangle)_{i,j=1}^n$ where $x_i$, $y_j$ are unit vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Then $\mathcal{D}$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ (equipped with usual Frobenius norm).

My attempt: since $\dim(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})=n^2<\infty$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{D}$ is closed and bounded. Boundedness is easy to verify by using Cauchy's inequality for each $\langle x_i,y_j\rangle$. But how do I show that $\mathcal{D}$ is closed? Or maybe we can use a different method to prove this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ supposed to be finite?

Comment: We can assume that $\mathcal{H}$ has finite dimension wlog because we only pick up $2n$ unit vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional, this is immediate because the space of $2n$-tuples of unit vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ is compact and the map taking such a tuple to the corresponding element of $\mathcal{D}$ is continuous.  If $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite-dimensional, then the set $\mathcal{D}$ obtained from $\mathcal{H}$ will be the same as the set that would be obtained from $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, since any choice of $x_i$ and $y_j$ is contained in some $2n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second sentence to prove the equality of the two sets you mention. The question I have, is that the $2n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ depends on the $x_i$ and $y_j$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: But all such $2n$-dimensional subspaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$.

Comment: My understanding is that any finitely dimensional inner product space is isometrically isomorphic to some $\mathbb{C}^m$. So picking up vectors from $\mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to choose them from $\mathbb{C}^m$. Note that inner product is preserved!